# Cayley Transform: well defined?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Why is the Cayley backtransformation well-defined:
$$A_U:=\imath(1+U)(1-U)^{-1}$$
In general $1-U$ is not invertible for example for $U=1$.

Comment: What kinds of operators $A$ and $U$ are we considering here? Bounded and selfadjoint $A$; unitary $U$? Or a more general case?

Comment: Only A symmetric and U isometric

Comment: $U=1$ is no counterexample, as this would imply $A-\imath = A + \imath$ on $\mathcal{D}(A)$, which is a contradiction if the domain is nontrivial.

Comment: For arbitrary unitary operators it does indeed break down if one doesn't restrict its domain. In other words one cannot obtain any unitary operator by the Cayley transform...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Caley transform is invertible on its range:

First it follows by symmetry:
$$\langle Ax,y\rangle=\langle x,Ay\rangle\Rightarrow \mathcal{N}(A+\imath)=\{0\}$$
So we have:
$$A+\imath:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{R}(A+\imath): \mathcal{N}(A+\imath)=\{0\}$$
$$A-\imath:\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{R}(A-\imath)$$
Especially:
$$U_A\text{ well defined}$$

Next by formal calculations it holds:
$$(1+U_A)(A+\imath)=2A$$
$$(1-U_A)(A+\imath)=2\imath\Rightarrow\mathcal{N}(\ldots)=\{0\}$$
Thus we also have:
$$(1+U_A)(A+\imath):\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{D}(A):x\mapsto 2Ax$$
$$(1-U_A)(A+\imath):\mathcal{D}(A)\to\mathcal{R}:x\mapsto 2\imath x,\mathcal{N}(\ldots)=\{0\}$$
Especially:
$$(1-U_A)\text{ invertible}$$

Concluding:
$$A_U=(1+U_A)(1-U_A)^{-1}=(1+U_A)(A+\imath)(A+\imath)^{-1}(1-U_A)^{-1}=A$$

Note that it was crucial that the isometric operator was given by the Cayley transform of a symmetric operator; otherwise the Cayley backtransformation is ill defined in general.

Comment: Your 'formal calculation' is in fact an identity on $\mathcal{D}(A)$

Comment: I know ;) but I want to stress that it is in first attempt purely formal since I didn't take care of domains but then surely afterwards it is valid on the domain ...but it is dangerous anyway since one might think it is the identity on all the space no only on the domain

Comment: A general densely-defined symmetric $A$ may have $\sigma(A)=\mathbb{C}$. If $A$ is maximally symmetric (i.e., has no proper symmetric extensions), then either $A=A^{\star}$, or the spectrum of $A$ is the closed half-space $\Im \lambda \ge 0$ or $\Im\lambda \le 0$. Everything can work if the $A$ is maximally symmetric and if $\sigma(A)$ is contained in the closed upper half-plane (if the spectrum is contained in the closed lower half-planed, then substitue $-A$ for $A$.) This is because $\Im i(1+z)/(1-z)=(1-|z|^{2})/|1-z|^{2} > 0$ for $|z| \le 1$.

Comment: Continuing the comment ... The isometry $U$ with $1$ in the resolvent set of $U$ or in the continuous spectrum of $U$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the maximally symmetric $A$ whose spectra are contained in the upper half-plane--the correspondence is through the Cayley transform.

Comment: Nice thanks ;)!